# In Excel, how can I narrow an uneven distribution of dates/times and corresponding values into an even distribution?

Tags: excel, database

To explain: we have a SCADA system running our water treatment plant. In, say, the three month time span we need flowrate or pressure data, when we extract the data, each data point corresponds to a change in slope.

That means we can have a data point for every other second, every other hour, or no data points for an entire day, depending on if the slopes are changing or not, and when. This wouldn't be a problem if we were simply graphing the data and using it visually. We also do percent runtime calculations which requires an even distribution of data.

The issue is we need data points corresponding to every single minute (i.e. I need 1440 data points per day).

Obviously the answer is some sort of interpolation. An example follows of what kind of fix I would need:

I have the data like this:

. .  .Date/time . . . .Value

1 1/1/20 0736.0 . . . 12.0

2 1/1/20 0736.3 . . . 12.12

3 1/1/20 0736.4 . . . 12.15

4 1/1/20 0738 . . . 12.9

5 1/1/20 0759 . . . 15.0

I would need the data like this:

. .  .Date/time . . . .Value

1 1/1/20 0736 . . . 12.0

2 1/1/20 0737 . . . 12.4

3 1/1/20 0738 . . . 12.9

4 1/1/20 0739 . . . 13.1

5 1/1/20 0740 . . . 13.3

.

Please let me know if you can think of anything. We have a quarterly report due soon that requires this data. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link for [exponential smoothing in Excel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0r5pK8mlcXM)

Smoothed minute value in Columns J is the final output. J6 = I6 - I5 and so on.

### **`Caution:`**

Note the data total in Column C is same as its cumulative total in Column H. But there is different smoothed cumulative total in Column I. Remember to adjust the difference somewhere. May be in J4 and J5.

[image]